# href attribute not working

Tags: javascript, html, href

HTML:

`<a id="Change">Click to change</a>`

```
<a href="image1_big.png" class="maneA blade">
<img id="maneP" src="image1.png"/></a>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
      $(function() {
 $('#Change').click(function(){
   $("#maneP").attr('src',"image2.png");
   $(".maneA").attr('href',"image2_big.png");

   return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

Why is the `href` attribute not changing? when the `src` one is?!

Comment: It actually does change in Chrome. Where does it not? http://jsfiddle.net/LgYTV/

Comment: Check your files for some typo.

Comment: @Aneri It doesn't seem to work in safari or firefox.

Comment: Maxmitch, [that fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LgYTV/) works absolutely right in Firefox. You can inspect the page with Page Inspector in Firefox, just press `Ctrl+Shift+i` and select the element. It normally changes the attribute.

Comment: @Stano It doesn't seem to do anything apart from make the mouse disappear? What am I looking for?

Comment: Well, updated that fiddle with existing images. It works right in Firefox just like in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/LgYTV/1/

Comment: @Stano How do I know that this fiddle is changing the href? I know only that it is changing the src

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="Change" href="#">Click to change</a>

<a href="image1_big.png" class="maneA blade">
<img id="maneP" src="image1.png"/></a>
```

This one should work. I just removed the return false statement

```
$(function() {
 $('#Change').click(function(){

      $("#maneP").attr('src',"image2.png");
      $(".maneA").attr('href',"image2_big.png");
      var href = $(".maneA").attr('href');
     alert(href);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UwVRX/

Comment: This has stopped the src working. And given it a weird alert... Why did you add that?

Comment: And also makes the page reload by removing the `return false` statement which does't look very good.